# How to clear values in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have created this function inside onChange to handle my inputs using react-select. it works perfectly fine in terms of submitting the input and using it later. The thing is, the clear property is not working. Before I created my function inside onChange, it used to work whenever I click on "x". Yet now it is not. Any help?

```
  {["role1", "role2", "role3"].map(role => (
          <Select
            cacheOptions
            defaultOptions
            loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
            key={role}
            getOptionLabel={i => i.full_name}
            getOptionValue={i => i.id}
            closeMenuOnSelect={false}
            isMulti
            className="selectStyle"
            placeholder={t(role)}
            value={form.users.filter(item => item.role === role)}
            onChange={values => {
              let newValues = form.users;

              values.forEach(item => {
                if (
                  newValues.filter(v => v.id === item.id && v.role === role)
                    .length
                ) {
                  return;
                }

                item.role = role;
                newValues.push(item);
              });

              setFormValue({ name: "users", value: newValues });
            }}
            clearValue={() => {
              setFormValue({
                name: "users",
                value: form.users.filter(item => item.role !== role)
              });
            }}
          />
```

I hope that I can get some help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you setting a value inside `clearValue`? shouldn't you be clearing the value?

Comment: I tried many times to use some functions to clear the values inside the input box but nothing happens every time I click on "x"

Comment: just set value to an `[]` and it should do the trick

Comment: it seems like that clearValue is not an event handler like onClick and onChange so it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this.setState.

```
        clearValue={() => {
          this.setState({
            name: "users",
            value: form.users.filter(item => item.role !== role)
          });
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where shall I add this? I already have a function in onChange..

Comment: clearValue={() => {
              this.setState({
                name: "users",
                value: form.users.filter(item => item.role !== role)});
        }}

Comment: It seems like that clearValue is not a valid property inside select so it didn't work. I have also tried to console.log anything to make sure if it is working or not but it doesn't. Is there any other way to handle this issue using onClick for example?!

Comment: `clearValue` is not a valid attribute of the attributes provided by `react-select`. Have a look:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

Moreover, when you want to clear your selected input?

Comment: I want to clear the values once I click on "x" on the left. This used to be working automatically before I used onChange I don't know why!